# How to check BIOS hard disk password status using Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, bios

Some hard disks support password protection on boot up. Is there a Win32 API that we can call to check for the hard disk password status?

The class: Win32_ComputerSystem doesn't seem to have a field on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1668007&group_id=136732&atid=736684

> It supports XP SP2 and 2003 if driver
>   implements ATA_PASS_THROUGH. It also
>   supports 2000 and XP SP1 if
>   undocumented IDE_PASS_THROUGH is
>   available.

MSDN documents [ATA_PASS_THROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (call DeviceIoControl).